# SonarQube does not analyze C# source code

Tags: c#, jenkins, module, sonarqube

I run SonarQube 6.7 to analyze C# code from Jenkins (MSBuild1 15.0). 
I expect the issues of C# analysis displaying on Sonar.

But the result of C# could not be shown on Sonar, while Other languages run OK.

Here is some in log file on Sonar-side:

```
2017.12.11 13:22:22 INFO  ce[AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Execute task | project=DemoKenny | type=REPORT | id=AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6 | submitter=admin
2017.12.11 13:22:52 ERROR ce[AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6][c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: DemoKenny
2017.12.11 13:22:52 ERROR ce[AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6][c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: DemoKenny
2017.12.11 13:22:52 ERROR ce[AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6][c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: DemoKenny
2017.12.11 13:22:52 ERROR ce[AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6][c.h.s.m.SonargraphMeasureComputer] Not processing for module: DemoKenny
2017.12.11 13:23:21 INFO  ce[AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Executed task | project=DemoKenny | type=REPORT | id=AWBEPRL8PozEI6LHTjk6 | submitter=admin | time=58474ms
```

How should it be fixed?

*Added at 12 Dec:*
I removed SonarGraph plugin, then the error above is disappeared, but C# result still was not displayed. Problem may be from Jenkins-side or Roslyn SDK.

> Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.

Here is the log file on Jenkins-side.
https://ufile.io/w93hl

Comment: What happens when you remove the SonarGraph plugin? Also, this is a server-side log. Should we intuit from that that analysis seems to run fine Jenkins-side?

Comment: I removed the `processing` tag. That tag is for the programming language called `Processing` and has nothing at all to do with your question. Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Comment: My project has "No tags" on Sonar (in Overview of project). Is my understanding same with yours? If not, where to find it?

Comment: I removed SonarGraph, but it did not help. But you're right, maybe problem in Jenkins-side. Pls check attach log file below on Jenkins side.

Comment: I solved my problem with support from valeri....@sonarsource.com. Sorry for my late response. Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/11YITqrltIk